# xcodebuild: error: Scheme MyApp is not currently configured for the test action. + returnValue=66

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcodebuild

I am facing the below error while running **xcodebuild** command.

**Command:**

```
$ xcodebuild clean build test -workspace MyApp -scheme MyApp
```

**Error:**

```
Scheme MyApp is not currently configured for the test action
```

I have analyzed and found that we need to enable the option **shared** in the scheme. But it is already enabled in my project and still getting this error.

Can help me to find the setting or missing flags? I have also tried to enable Run under Test.

[image]

Comment: i'm also facing the same problem.Did you found any solution to this?

Comment: Are you able to run tests? @Gobi M